# Some troubles with FileCreate

Tags: winapi, rust

I use winapi crate to get handle of the file. But I have troubles with encoding or something like that when I try to use absolute file path. So windows always returns error 3 (path not found).

When I was trying to debug this problem I was using `GetFullPathNameW` to resolve full path. 
For example path like `a.txt` and even `\\a.txt` work well but when I use path like `foo\\bar\\baaaaz.txt` after resolving it I receive something like `C:\Users\Path\To\Project\鋨駨foo\baaaaz.txt`

Macro that expands my strings

```
macro_rules! c {
    ($str: expr) => {
        unsafe {
        let v: Vec<u16> = OsStr::new($str).encode_wide().chain(Some(0).into_iter()).collect();
        v.as_ptr()
    }
    };
}
```

Method that should opens handle of the file

```
fn open_file_handle(name: &str) -> Result<HANDLE, u32> {


    let handle: HANDLE = unsafe {
        CreateFileW(
            c!(name),
            FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_READ_DATA | SYNCHRONIZE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            NULL as LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL
        )
    };

   if handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE {
       let error = unsafe { GetLastError() };
       Err(error)
   } else {
       Ok(handle)
   }
```

And method that I use to resolve full names

```
fn resolve(name: &str) -> String {

   unsafe {
       let result = GetFullPathNameW(
            c!(name),
            512,
            buffer.as_mut_ptr(),
            NULL as *mut LPWSTR
        );
       buffer.set_len(result as usize);
    }

    String::from_utf16_lossy(buffer.as_slice())
}
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `c` macro gets a pointer to a temporary variable. This causes undefined behaviour.